# Windows 7 phone keyboard

Tags: windows-phone-7, keyboard

I want to remap the keys to colemac any ideas. I have done a bunch of searching.  Does anyone know how to remap the keys?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot remap the keys in windows phone.. not at least without hacking.

The reason is that no API is exposed to allow such a manipulation. If you just care about doing it locally / not releasing it into store, hop onto XDA devs and you will find some dllimport / keyboard work there.